# Running SQLite 3 in MicroApache

Tags: php, windows, apache, sqlite

I'm running MicroApache (http://microapache.amadis.sytes.net) on Windows XP and would like to use SQLite 3 databases.

The PHP version is 5.2.9-2.

My MicroApache version has SQLite 2 support through 2 lines in the php.ini:
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_sqlite.dll

I test whether the extension works in 3 ways:
1. phpinfo()
2. extension_loaded() and get_loaded_extensions()
3. using sample code that var_dump()s the constant SQLITE3_NUM (should be the integer 2)
   and tries to create a database (error: class 'SQLite3' does not exist)

Things I have tried (if I can remember them all):
1. copied php_sqlite3.dll from a full installation of PHP and added "extension=php_sqlite3.dll" to php.ini
    -> error "Procedure entry point gc_remove_zval_from_buffer was not found in php5ts.dll"
2. compressed the DLL with UPX (like the other DLLs of MicroApache seem to be)
    -> does not display an error on start, nor in the log file, but does not work
3. tried various things with php.ini
  - created a section "[sqlite3]"
  - prefixed "sqlite3." to "extension_dir=." and "extension=php_sqlite3.dll"
  - ...
4. tried to use PDO, it says it 'could not find driver'

Who can help me get SQLite 3 to work?

Answer (score 2):

The problem of connecting to SQLite 3 DBs and similar problems are covered and discussed on a forum post entitled, ["Connecting to SQLite3 database from PHP 5.25"](http://www.issociate.de/board/post/469813/Connecting_to_SQLite3_database_from_PHP_5.25.html) This may answer some of your queries.

The latest build of SQLite is compiled-in to PHP5 and is enabled via PDO.

It shows in PHPINFO.PHP as

> 2.0-dev "$Id: sqlite.c,v 1.166.2.13.2.12 2008/12/31 11:17:44 sebastian Exp $"

Sounds more like a problem with the test code. Have you cross-checked by running on an SQLite system with standard Apache and the same version of PHP?  What are the result from `phpinfo()`, etc?

The recent MicroApache distros come with a PHP/SQLite guestbook as a demo/test. Does this not work?

Come to think of it you may not have spotted that there's an SQLite distro. Why not revisit the site and check the other versions out (just unzip and run).

- [MicroApache 2.0.63+PHP 4.4.9+SQLite:](http://microapache.amadis.sytes.net/bin/MicroApache-2.0.63-PHP-4.4.9-SQLite.zip)

As always I point out that MicroApache isn't intended to be used on a public-facing webserver without paying specific attention to the security config. It was developed merely as a way of sharing information locally via floppy or USB stick. It's easy enough to harden though.

I'm sure you are aware that the SQLite developer renamed a number of the functions with the advent of SQLite3 including the open function - (See here: [An Introduction To The SQLite C/C++ Interface](http://sqlite.org/cintro.html) ) - I'm not sure how this has been handled by the PHP developers including this codebase into PHP. The suggestion from the page linked above is that you can open PHp3 DBs "as is" with the right PHP code.

Mixing DLLs from different distros of PHP isn't recommended. I don't recommend any other use of the MicroApache distro other than "as is". Adding or mixing DLLs from differing versions of PHP etc. to MicroApache may introduce serious bugs or security problems.

There has been little or no interest in SQLite with MicroApache to date so I've really not dug too deeply into it other than to check the functionality works.
I don't rely too heavily on what's reported by `phpinfo()`.

Perhaps you can update with your info to confirm if the version being reported is accurate.

**Update**

I've had time to research a little more and a discussion on [php5-sqlite3 at the Mac OS Forge mailing list](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2009-January/013658.html) answers your problem.

The PHP implementation is partial and not well documented. Some SQLite3 procedural function calls are only exposed by an object based hierarchy. The procedural API only offers the ability to open SQLite 2 DBs so you're stuck with using objects by the looks of it.

> There is also a PECL extension, php-sqlite3, which was
>   developed   during 2008, currently at
>   version 0.6. This is what the
>   php5-sqlite3   port installs. But it
>   does not provide the sqlite3_open
>   function you   are seeking. Rather, it
>   gives you an object-oriented interface
>   based   around three classes: SQLite3,
>   SQLite3Stmt and SQLite3Result. It is
>   described here, rather incompletely,
>   notably the installation
>   instructions are totally missing:

- [MicroApache 2.0.63+PHP 5.2.9+SQLite](http://microapache.amadis.sytes.net/bin/MicroApache-2.0.63-PHP-5.2.9-SQLite.zip)
- [MicroApache 1.3.41+PHP 4.4.9+SQLite](http://microapache.amadis.sytes.net/bin/MicroApache-1.3.41-PHP-4.4.9-SQLite.zip)
- [MicroApache 1.3.41+PHP 4.4.9+SQLite](http://microapache.amadis.sytes.net/bin/MicroApache-1.3.41-PHP-4.4.9-SQLite.zip)
- [MicroApache 1.3.41+PHP 4.4.9+SQLite+GD2](http://microapache.amadis.sytes.net/bin/MicroApache-1.3.41-PHP-4.4.9-SQLite-GD2.zip)

Hopefully you can play with these distros and solve your problems.

There is an SQLite3.DLL included with the distro as a courtesy which can be accessed directly from VB5/6 or any compatible language which can call the DLL.

- [Using SQLITE 3 from Visual BASIC 5](http://vbtoolbox.kerys.co.uk/sqlite/index.htm)

This was a separate project I had a look at some while ago. This was produced in MSVC by editing the original source. This DLL isn't compatible with PHP/PDO but could be used via a CGI interface. Alternately the original SQLite 3 DLL could be obtained and used via Delphi etc.

Comment: Moderator note: This answer was pieced together from 8 different answers 'in parts'. Please tie it together more and improve it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that I do have the distro with SQLite support. However it only has support for version 2, not 3.

> My MicroApache version has SQLite 2 support [...]

I would like to use SQLite 3 because it is faster, I could interact with the databases I created for a project in Delphi and I could access the newly created databases with the Firefox extension SQLite Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I've tinkered with this problem some more, but could still not create/access a SQLite 3 database.

Interestingly, the link you provided in Part 1 mentions a class "SQLiteDatabase" which is not found in the PHP documentation and is not part of the SQLite3 extension (which is object oriented - as mentioned in your last post, Mad Max).

"SQLiteDatabase" creates a database, but when you open it, you can see that it is in version 2.1.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:
PDO works only when I use the DSN prefix "sqlite2" which is not very surprising, since phpinfo() only lists the driver "sqlite2" under the section "PDO".